# Fetching data or any method to get auth data

Tags: javascript, request, axios, fetch, apollo-server

In server.js(port 4000) I got this route:

```
// Auth middleware that checks if the user is logged in
const isLoggedIn = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.user) {
      next();
  } 
  else {
      res.sendStatus(401);
  }
}

app.get('/good', isLoggedIn, (req, res) => res.send(req.user));
```

or even this:

```
app.get('/good', (req, res) => res.send(req.user));
```

Innitially I wanted to get user data with graphql query, but whatever. Now I want to get this req.user data into my react component, client is on port 3000( I just want to know if I'm logged in or not). I tried with fetch and with axios, but it seems, that it didn't see req.user, ( but when I use isLoggedIn function it can see that req.user is = "", and it shows Error 401, as function is constructed).

on http://localhost:4000/good data is displayed correctly.

Here's more details:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require('path');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('dotenv').config();
const passport = require('passport');
require('./modules/auth');

const cookieSession = require('cookie-session');

// #6 Initialize an Express application
const app = express();

// app.use(cors());

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    credentials: true
  })
);

app.use(cookieSession({
  name: 'session',
  keys: ['key1', 'key2']
}))

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile','email'] }));
app.get('/auth/google/callback', passport.authenticate('google', {
  successRedirect: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql',
  failureRedirect: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql',
}));


// Auth middleware that checks if the user is logged in
const isLoggedIn = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.user) {
      next();
  } 
  else {
      res.sendStatus(401);
  }
}


app.get('/good', isLoggedIn, (req, res) => res.send(req.user));

// route for logging out
app.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
  req.session = null;
  req.logout();
  res.redirect('/');
  });




// Connect to Mongo and Apollo Server( skipped that, it's not the case)

// #7 Use the Express application as middleware in Apollo server( server was Apollo Server)
server.applyMiddleware({ app });

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'))
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));
```

Bonus:
here's additional ApolloServer idea:

server.js(skipped part):

```
const { ApolloServer } = require('apollo-server-express');

const typeDefs = require('./modules/graphqlschemas/index');
const resolvers = require('./modules/resolvers/index');

// #5 Initialize an Apollo server
const server = new ApolloServer({ 
  typeDefs: typeDefs,
  resolvers: resolvers,
  // context: ({ req, res }) => ({ req, res }) 
  context: ({ req }) => ({
    getUser: () => req.user,
    logout: () => req.logout(),
  })
});
```

User resolver( part with current User query):

```
module.exports = {
  Query: {
    users: () => User.find({}),
    currentUser: (parent, args, context) => context.getUser()
  },
...
```